# Will `TcpStream` be disabled once it receives an invalid UTF-8?

Tags: rust, tcp, telnet, rust-tokio

I'm trying to create a server that receives a string from a client through TCP socket communication and returns the same string to the same socket. I want the following specifications:

- Repeat communication with the client (corresponding to the `loop` block in the code below)
- When the client receives a valid UTF-8 character, return the same character (`Ok` branch in the `loop` block)
- When the client does not receive a valid UTF-8 character, return the string `"Invalid data"` (`Err` branch in the `loop` block)

```rust
use std::io::Error;
use tokio::io::{AsyncBufReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, BufReader};
use tokio::net::TcpListener;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    // Create TCP listener
    let addr = "localhost:8080";
    let socket = TcpListener::bind(&addr).await;
    let listener = socket.unwrap();

    // Accept connection
    let (mut socket, _addr) = listener.accept().await.unwrap();

    // Split socket into read and write halves
    let (reader, mut writer) = socket.split();

    // Read buffer into string
    let mut line = String::new();
    let mut buf_reader = BufReader::new(reader);
    loop {
        match buf_reader.read_line(&mut line).await {
            Ok(bytes) => {
                if bytes == 0 {
                    // `bytes == 0` means the connection is closed 
                    break;
                }
            }
            Err(error) => {
                println!("{error}");
                line = "Invalid data".to_string();
            }
        }
        // Respond to client
        writer.write_all(line.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
        line.clear();
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

The client is `telnet` on macOS.

```bash
telnet localhost 8080
```

Below are how to reproduce the issue:

- Typing `"hello"` returns `"hello"`.
- Typing ctrl-C and pressing Enter shows `"stream did not contain valid UTF-8"` on the server side and no response from the server is displayed on the telnet side (I want `"Invalid data"` to be displayed).
- Typing `"hello"` again returns nothing, even though I have confirmed that the server is receiving it.

telnet output:

```
hello
hello
^C
hello
```

Will the `TcpStream` become invalid once invalid UTF-8 is received?

#### Expected behaviours

- The server returns "`Invalid data`" when it receives invalid UTF-8 characters.
- The server returns the same characters it receives if they are valid UTF-8 characters, even after receiving invalid UTF-8 characters in the previous `loop`.

Comment: I think this is just an issue with the special handling done by `telnet`. Normally ctrl-C would kill the process, but telnet intercepts it and sends a control sequence (which seems to be invalid UTF-8). I suspect the third "Hello" is also caused by a quirk of telnet. Maybe try `nc localhost 8080` instead, and try sending random invalid UTF-8 bytes instead of whatever telnet sends when you press ctrl-C. You'll probably need to use a pipe or something.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with `telnet`.
I created `invalid.csv` which contains 3 rows alternating between valid and invalid rows of UTF-8 sequences:

**invalid.csv**

```
hello
(invalid UTF-8 sequences)
hello
```

Then, I used a pipe with `nc` command:

```bash
cat invalid.csv | nc localhost 8080
```

The output was:

```
hello
Invalid data
hello
```

which is as expected.